# JS function to check if a date is in the correct format

Tags: javascript, datetime, validation

I wrote the following JS function to check if a date comes in the right format and can be used further down in the application

```
const getInvalidDay = day => {
  const date = new Date(day);
  const dateToMoments = [date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds(), date.getUTCMilliseconds()];
  return dateToMoments.some(moment => moment !== 0);
};
```

An example snippet to see how it works

```js
const getInvalidDay = day => {
  const date = new Date(day);
  const dateToMoments = [date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds(), date.getUTCMilliseconds()];
  return dateToMoments.some(moment => moment !== 0);
};

console.log('Should be true - not valid::: ', getInvalidDay('2021-03-16T09:00:00.000Z'));
console.log('Should be false - is valid::: ', getInvalidDay('2021-03-16'));
```

When we have all moments as `0` means the date is valid so we return `false`

instead, if some have `!==0` then it is `true` and the date is not valid

I was wondering if there is another way to achieve the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An invalid date will be recognized by the Date object, as you can see here.

```js
console.log('invalid date: ', new Date('hello world').toString());
console.log('valid date: ', new Date('2022-07-03T12:55:10.176Z').toString());
```

[MDN documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value):

> Calling new Date() (the Date() constructor) returns a Date object. If called with an invalid date string, or if the date to be constructed will have a UNIX timestamp less than -8,640,000,000,000,000 or greater than 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds, it returns a Date object whose toString() method returns the literal string Invalid Date.

So by definition you could check if a date is invalid by simply doing:

```js
console.log(new Date('hello world').toString() === "Invalid Date")
```

Another option is to check the date instance passed to [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) as indicated in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript).

```js
console.log('is valid: ', !isNaN(new Date('hello world')));
console.log('is valid: ', !isNaN(new Date()));
```